# How to find the width and height of a specific cell in a GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking to find the width and height of a specific row and column number in a GridLayout from inside the activity code, during Runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by creating a dummy layout in `xml` as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_dummy_1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
```

I then obtained the total dimension of the 4 columns by calling

```
    dummyLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l_dummy_1);
    width = dummyLayout.getWidth();
    height = dummyLayout.getHeight();
```